# Displaying image to a page from uploads folder using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to display my uploaded image in a page. I used dropzone in uploading the image.

Controller:

```
public function do_uploadlogo($id){
 $restologo=$_POST['restologo'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/restaurants/logos/';
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
    $data = array(
        'restologo' => 'uploads/restaurants/logos/'.$fileName
    );
    $this->load->database('findiningcebu');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('restaurants',$data);
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
 }
 public function addrestologolink($id){
    $data = array(

            "action" => base_url('/index.php/AdminController/do_uploadlogo/'.$id), 
            "data" => $this->db->get_where('restaurants',array('id'=>$id))  
    );   

    $this->load->view('admin/logo',$data);
}
```

View

```
<div class="del" style="padding-left: 15px">Current Logo:</div>
<div class="del" style="padding-left: 15px"><img src="<?=base_url().$restologo?>" /></div>
```

Please help!

Comment: where is restologo variable in your data array in addrestologolink method? i think you need to pass restologo variable.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console, or is the image just not displaying?

Comment: im not getting any error. The image won't display. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<div class="del" style="padding-left: 15px">
<?php
 echo'<img src="' . base_url().'uploads/restaurants/logos/' . $restologo . '">';
?>
```